# Can someone give example(s) of projective non-singular algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: examples-counterexamples

I may know that the term "projective" relates to kind of virtual added points at infinity of the variety.

I may know that the term "non-singular" relates to the fact that the variety has no singular points and that it might have a link with an idea of possible differentiation.

I may know what "algebraic" means, but it can refer to algebraic topology, or algebraic number theory. I would not really know how to have enough discernment here.

The term variety is, to me, today, too large, to explain. I don't really know what it is in mathematics.

$\mathbb{C}$ is the set of complex numbers, we can write like $a+ib$ where $i^2 = -1$.

"over $\mathbb{C}$" is also a mystery to me. Could it mean "made by/of" complex numbers? or "in complex numbers related spaces"?

Is it possible to write the question with symbols and quantifiers? at least a certain number of?

Comment: Not sure the question is a good fit for MSE. If you're coming from outside complex algebraic geometry, perhaps the shortest path to examples is to learn about $n$-dimensional _complex projective space_ (a.k.a. "the set of complex lines through the origin in complex Cartesian $(n+1)$-dimensional space"). This formalizes "adding points at infinity" in a uniform way. Then look at loci of one or more homogeneous polynomials in $(n+1)$ complex variables (subject to differential or algebraic conditions to ensure smoothness). [...]

Comment: It may also help to add tags to the question, perhaps algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-varieties, projective-space, ....